# Override WooCommerce Frontend Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, overriding, woocommerce

Can someone guide me as to what is the proper method of overriding WooCommerce core Javascript files, specifically frontend files. I have not found any documentation on this and looking at the code, the path to the frontend script files is hard coded in the plugin so I doubt that placing an assets folder in my theme will do anything.

What is the cleanest way to to this so that I can load a file located in my theme dir?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to completely disable their scripting, or override a particular behavior or event?

Comment: Well I was going to completely overwrite the javascript file (add-to-cart-variation.js) because there are quite a few changes I need to make.

Comment: In that file, it looks like there are only two events being bound on doc ready. You could just unbind them in your own script. line-4, and line-216 https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.js. I haven't worked with that plugin, but I assume you could manually modify that file, too.

Comment: I needed to dequeue them all. This has nice list of ALL the included woocommerce frontend css and javascript files. This is what I needed to work with: http://gregrickaby.com/remove-woocommerce-styles-and-scripts/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I had the same problem except with add-to-cart.js.  Simple solution is to DEQUEUE the woocommerce script and ENQUEUE your replacement.  In my case I added the following to my functions.php:

```
wp_dequeue_script('wc-add-to-cart');
wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ). '/js/add-to-cart-multi.js' , array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
```

You would want to DEQUEUE the 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' script.  I don't think you *have* to ENQUEUE with the same name, but I couldn't see a reason not to.

Hope this helps.

If you're using WordPress Version 4.0.1 and WooCommerce Version 2.2.10. You can use the following scripts:

```
wp_deregister_script('wc-add-to-cart');
wp_register_script('wc-add-to-cart', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ). '/js/add-to-cart-multi.js' , array( 'jquery' ), WC_VERSION, TRUE);
wp_enqueue_script('wc-add-to-cart');
```

Comment: it's ''better'' to enqueue with the same name, so you won't break any dependency it may have.

Comment: If you do try to enqueue with the same handle then original file still gets enqueued unless you deregister the original handle with `wp_dequeue_script()` before you re-enqueue it.

Comment: Could you please check my question also http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/215238/how-to-add-quick-edit-in-woocommerce-order-section

Answer (score 36):

WooCommerce loads frontend scripts and styles in `class-wc-frontend-scripts.php` file, and there can be found how the scripts are registered, enqueued, localized and dependencies.

The preferred place to enqueue scripts in Wordpress is the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook, because that is the moment after Wordpress is fully loaded but before any output is made. And also I like to enqueue all my related script and styles in one section of code.

When you want to completely remove some scripts, calling either `wp_deregister_script()` or `wp_dequeue_script()` is enough. But sometimes if want to make some changes and leave the existing dependencies, variables and localization there is a problem because plugins are loaded before themes. So enqueue functions will not work as you would expect. Simple `wp_dequeue_script() => wp_enqueue_script()` will [not work](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#notes), `wp_deregister_script() => wp_register_script`() will work, but localized data will be lost.

---

This can be solved by working directly with `$wp_scripts` global object that contains and manages all the scripts loaded through `wp_enqueue_script()` or registered with `wp_register_script()`:

```
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_theme_scripts' );

    function load_theme_scripts() {
        global $wp_scripts; 
        $wp_scripts->registered[ 'wc-add-to-cart' ]->src = get_template_directory_uri() . '/woocommerce/js/wc-add-to-cart.js';
    }
```

Comment: I liked the `$wp_scripts` option because that way I don't disturb / need to bother about script dependencies or version etc. +1

Comment: This is seriously such an amazing answer! I had no idea you could work with or that there even was an `$wp_scripts` object that you could modify. This is amazing! I want to buy you a beer!

Comment: Thanks! Actually, my copied script (wc-single-product) isn't working without localized data so this fixed a big issue for me :) Note that you need to use "get_stylesheet_directory_uri" instead of "get_template_directory_uri" in a child theme.

Answer (score 2):

Add this section to your function.php

```
function themeslug_enqueue_script() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'add-to-cart-variation', get_bloginfo( 'url' ). '/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.js', false );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_script' );
```