# Change Woocmmerce Default Payment gateway Based on Add To Cart Button

Tags: php, woocommerce, payment-gateway

On my woocommerce single product pages I have added a duplicate “Add to cart” button,Now Two Add to cart button in single product page.if it was possible when someone clicks the first add to cart button and gets redirected to the checkout page that we could have the payment option of “First Payment Gateway” open as the default?Same as i want someone clicks the second add to cart button and gets redirected to the checkout page that we could have the payment option of “Second Payment Gateway” open as the default

Comment: were you able to resolve this? I am looking to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can override checkout.js and achieve this.

Have a look here: [How To Prevent Woocommerce from selecting default payment method on Checkout page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967427/how-to-prevent-woocommerce-from-selecting-default-payment-method-on-checkout-pag)